# Trouble passing array of child class as parameter to child of parent class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

I have an abstract parent class, let's call it A, and three child classes that inherit from it: a_B, a_C, and a_D. I have a sorting method that should be able to sort an array of any of these classes (a_B, a_C, or a_D) based on a rating property that they inherit from their parent, A.

I am having trouble implementing this, however.

Here's essentially what I have:

```
class A {
protected:
    int rating;
    A(int r) {
        this->rating = r;
    }
public:
    int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    virtual void abstractStuff() = 0;
}

class a_B : public A {
    int property;
public:
    a_B(int r, int p) : A(r) {
        this->property = p;
    }
    void abstractStuff() {
        cout << "a_B" << endl;
    }
}


class a_C : public A {
    float property;
public:
    a_B(int r, float p) : A(r) {
        this->property = p;
    }
    void abstractStuff() {
        cout << "a_C" << endl;
    }
}


class a_D : public A {
    string property;
public:
    a_B(int r, string p) : A(r) {
        this->property = p;
    }
    void abstractStuff() {
        cout << "a_D" << endl;
    }
}


void sort(A* arr[]) {
    //sort implementation
}


int main() {
    a_B arr[5];
    //code to give each element of arr unique properties
    sort (arr); //doesn't work; this is where I'm kind of unclear about what to do
}
```

The last part, where I sort arr, is unclear to me. I'm not sure if I should pass a_B*, as a pointer, or maybe to cast it to type A, like `(A) a_B` or `(A*) a_B` or something of the sort.

**edit:**

The compiler gives me an error of an `invalid conversion from a_B to A**`.

Comment: Your base class constructor should be public and the `rating` variable should be private. Using protected is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely your sort function takes an array of pointers to base class A, as the only argument. Probably, the idea is to achieve type erasure (to place in array elements of different dynamic types) and further you will be able to treat elements polymorphically. So, your arr argument will contain elements of type A*, and when you extract some element from array, you can extract its rating member for sorting purpose. Very important, you need to change to

> a_B arr[5]; to A* arr[5];

also, every class constructor has the same name as class, so if we suppose that you made mistype, for example class a_D should looked like

```
class a_D : public A {
    string property;
public:
    a_D(int r, string p) : A(r) {
        this->property = p;
    }
    void abstractStuff() {
        cout << "a_D" << endl;
    }
}
```

To mention also, that A as a base class, in implementation like yours, should have virtual destructor, or you will have leaks!!!

Further, to populate an array to be passed to sort, you need some kind of space allocated for array, on stack or heap (you choose stack), what ever, but be careful about lifetime issues, anyway. Once, when you have space for elements of an array of A* every element can be populated with A* which can be initialized with a_B* or a_C* or pointer to object of any derived class from A. Such an array, you can pass to sort function as argument, without any casting.

example code, you should be able to compile and run out of the box:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    protected:
        int rating;
    A(int r) {
        this->rating = r;
    }
public:
    int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    virtual ~A(){} 
    virtual void abstractStuff() = 0;
};

class a_B : public A {
    int property;
public:
    a_B(int r, int p) : A(r) {
        this->property = p;
    }
    void abstractStuff() {
        cout << "a_B" << endl;
    }
};


class a_C : public A {
    float property;
public:
    a_C(int r, float p) : A(r) {
        this->property = p;
    }
    void abstractStuff() {
        cout << "a_C" << endl;
    }
};


class a_D : public A {
    string property;
public:
    a_D(int r, string p) : A(r) {
        this->property = p;
    }
    void abstractStuff() {
        cout << "a_D" << endl;
    }
};

template<class T, size_t N>
void printRatings(T*(&arr)[N]) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        cout<< "rating["<< i <<"] = " << arr[i]->getRating() << "\n";
    }
}


int main() {
    A* arr[5];

    a_B b(1,1);
    a_C c(2,2.);
    a_D d(3,"3");

    arr[0] = &b;
    arr[1] = &c;
    arr[2] = &d;
    arr[3] = &c;
    arr[4] = &b;
    printRatings (arr); //this works
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that I used template function printRatings which takes 
array of pointers to type T and deduces array size, so it can safely iterate through it.
the same idea you can use to make your sort function which will be like:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void sort(T*(&arr)[N]) {
    // sorting impl
}
```

and you will be able to pass A* arr[5] argument to it.